# s3 ansible module for file count in bucket

Tags: ansible

Ansible 2.3

Currently we are using shell command to find the file count.

```
 - name: Check if the file exists
   shell: >
     aws s3 ls s3://some-bucket/{{a}}/{{b}}/c/some-template.yml
     | wc -l
   register: fileCount
```

---

We are making sure.. the file exist

How to perform the file count using `s3` ansible module?

**Edit:** `a` & `b` is a variable, question edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ansible has `s3` and `aws_s3` module.

In ansible verison 2.3 you can use following method
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/s3_module.html

```
- name: List keys simple
  s3:
    bucket: mybucket
    mode: list
    prefix: a/b/c
  register: foo
- name: when you need the result
  debug: var={{foo.s3_keys |length}}
```

and if your version is higher，maybe you should use `aws_s3`
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/aws_s3_module.html

```
- name: List keys simple
  aws_s3:
    bucket: mybucket
    mode: list
```

Comment: Am using ansible 2.3------how to grab the output of this s3 module? Like `fileCount` in query

Comment: you can register a variable,then use it. example,register: foo
then debug: var = {{ foo|length }}
```

Comment: Am sorry... am new to ansible syntax. Are you asking me to write another task? Please update the answer

Comment: yes, register it, use the length method when you use it.

Comment: Can you please add it in the answer?

Comment: Already updated，note that  the {{ foo }} should be a list so that the length method can be used

Comment: How to mention exact path within the bucket?

Comment: the prefix argument may be you want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198019/discussion-between-gourds-and-overexchange).